Apache Camel Vert.x WebSocket client Connections health check in Spring Boot
I'm trying to implement a WebSocket client using Apache Camel with Vert.x in my Spring Boot application. I want to manage the connection state and perform health checks to see if the WebSocket connection is active.
Requirements:
Track the connection state (connected/disconnected).
Implement a health check endpoint that reflects the WebSocket connection status.
